# Load data to treeview asp.net

Tags: asp.net

If I have this `[Terminal] table`:

```
ID bigint
Description varchar(20)
TerminalLevel smallint //1 = Terminal, 2 = Sub Terminal, 3 = Sub-sub-Terminal
TerminalID             //0 = Main Terminal itself, else belong to parent terminal
```

For example, I have:

```
ID           Description           TerminalLevel         TerminalID
1            Terminal 1            1                     0
2            Terminal 1-1          2                     1
3            Terminal 1-1-1        3                     2
4            Terminal 2            1                     0
5            Terminal 2-1          1                     4
```

I expect to load the data to the tree like this:

```
Terminal 1
  |---> Terminal 1-1
           |---> Terminal 1-1-1
Terminal 2
  |---> Terminal 2-1
```

Would it be possible to select only one query and load to a treeview in asp.net?

Comment: if you are using sqldatareader you only need to order by terminalid and with advance of terminallevel you can use my solution, if you are using datatable or store data in a collection, you can use the solution of two functions to bind treeview one have parentNode of tree ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get you query in a `sqldatareader DReader` but order by `TerminalID` to avoid child to be added before parent
and use the following functions

```
SqlDataReader DReader = load from databse order by TerminalID ...
TreeNode nodeNew;
    if (DReader.HasRows)
    while (DReader.Read())
        {
            nodeNew = new TreeNode(DReader["Description"].ToString(), DReader["ID"].ToString());
            if(DReader["TerminalID"].ToString() == "0")
                 treeview.Nodes.Add(nodeNew);
            else
             treeview.FindNode(DReader["TerminalLevel"].ToString().Replace("-","/")).ChildNodes.Add(nodeNew);

        }
```

**UPDATE**

if you are using sqldatareader you only need to order by terminalid and with advance of terminallevel you can use my solution, if you are using datatable or store data in a collection, you can use the solution of two functions to bind treeview one have parentNode of tree ...

but here you have terminal level so you can search in node by path

**My Regards**

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just `select * from Terminal` and then build the tree out of that.  Or you could do a recursive query and spit out the results as xml.  But sql result sets do not have the notion of hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudo code for what you can try

```
mainTerminals = select Terminals where TerminalId=0
  foreach (terminal in mainTerminals)
     Create treeNode and initialize with terminal details
     Add treeNode to Tree
     call AddChildTerminals(terminal, treeNode) 
  end foreach


function AddChildTerminals(terminal, parentTreenode)
   childTerminals = select terminals where TerminalId=terminal.ID
   foreach (childTerminal in childTerminals )
     Create treeNode and initialize with childTerminal  details
     Add treeNode to parentTreenode
     call AddChildTerminals(childTerminal, treeNode) 
   end foreach
```

The two loops look very similar. If you possibly refactor so it's just one loop but I'll leave that out for now.